# Summary of ActionScript 3 strict mode

Tags: actionscript-3, strict

Where can I get a summary of differences between ActionScript 3.0 strict and standard mode? In other words, what are the things I can do in standard mode but not in strict mode?

Comment: You should be aware that the flex SDK compiler is stricter than the Flash Authoring enviroment in strict mode.
So there's not only actionscript strict and standard, there's also different compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn, I was trying to remember all night long where I've seen theses differences and I suddenly had a total recall in the shower this morning :p

http://books.google.fr/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=essential+actionscript+3.0+compiler+standard+strict&source=bl&ots=cuTT2kfUE-&sig=yIAPZCISoWSi6Hx1DIqH83BOljU&hl=fr&ei=MqQbStjNKIaQjAfx06nuDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. In case the link dies sometimes in the future, the referenced book is Par Colin Moock: Essential Actionscript, Chapter 7, Section "Strict-Mode Versus Standard-Mode Compilation", page 135